# How can I set a WebSphere classloader policy to PARENT_LAST for an app created in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

Our company is currently using RAD to develop our Java apps, but we're looking to move to Eclipse with the WebSphere Developer Tools. The pilot for our transition is going pretty well, except we're running into a classloader policy issue for new applications that are originally created in Eclipse, not RAD. Our projects that were originally created by RAD are deployed with the correct classloader policy (PARENT_LAST) when published via Eclipse because we originally used the Deployment Descriptor Editor in RAD which set the proper classloader policy in `/src/main/application/META-INF/ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell/applications/defaultApp/deployments/defaultApp/deployment.xml`. But now with Eclipse & WebSphere Developer Tools, we no longer have the nice Deployment Descriptor Editor UI to create or modify this file for us (apparently [it's not included with the WDT plugin](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=72758e1c-8868-4b5e-9c99-f539882db6ca)).

So, my question then is what is the best way to go about setting this classloader policy? We still need some new apps to have the classloader policy of PARENT_LAST set when we deploy them to our local servers. Our team has though about this a bit and we can see 4 options at the moment.

1. Open the Admin Console after every publish and change it. This would be a huge pain, and is pretty much not even a real option.
2. Change the server profile setting to use a PARENT_LAST classloader policy for all apps. This however is not the case for all the apps at our company, and would not work for all groups.
3. Run a jython script after every publish to set the classloader policy. This is slightly better than option 1, but not by much.
4. Manually create a deployment.xml file in the same location as the other apps created by RAD with the same structure as the deployment.xml files created by RAD, and modify it as necessary for each app.

Option 4 seems to be the best of the bunch, but it's still a manual process and somewhat error prone. Even if most of our developers can grok this approach for new apps, it would be most ideal if this were a simple one button click type process.

So given the fact that IBM has omitted the Deployment Descriptor Editor from the WDT plugin it would seem as if option 4 is our only hope, but I'll ask once more, is there any other better way to set a WebSphere classloader policy to PARENT_LAST for an app when that app is created in Eclipse? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Eclipse is free, while Rational Application Developer costs about $5,000 per year (per developer). The nice Deployment Editor (which wasn't that nice. It tends to include all sorts of things that aren't needed. Who needs that Derby DataSource defined there, anyway?) is one of the things you have to give up for saving tons of cash on an annual basis.

I'm digressing.

Option (1) is a complete no-no. You don't want to rely on manual steps for deployments; you should strive to automate deployments to the extent possible.

Option (2) *might* do. I am not sure which flavour of WebSphere you're using, but if you're using the Network Deployment edition, then you can design a WebSphere topology that consists of multiple servers and clusters. You could, theoretically, come up with such a topology whereby `PARENT_LAST` applications run on a specific server (or cluster) and `PARENT_FIRST` applications run on another server (or cluster).

You may be able to combine option (2) with a technical initiative to have all of your applications work with `PARENT_LAST`. This is the recommended approach if your application is using popular third-party libraries that WebSphere happens to use as well (for its own internal purposes). For example, if you're using Commons Lang, then you're already recommended to switch to `PARENT_LAST` because WebSphere uses its own internal copy of Commons Lang that might conflict with yours.

Option (3) - it's of course better than option (1) but isn't necessarily worse than option (2) if you can get your WebSphere topology right.

Option (4) is harder to implement but I believe it's the best approach overall:

1. It's a one-time setup effort for each EAR (and for each WAR that exists within the EAR).
2. Once it's done, deployment can easily be automated as no extra steps are needed.
3. If you're working with a local test environment to test your code, and you're rapidly publishing applications from your workspace into your local test environment, then this approach is the only approach (other than option (2)) that will work for you without extra manual work.

If none works... consider paying $5,000 per year (per user) and get option (5) - use IBM's editor. Or, better off... hire someone to design an Eclipse plugin that will do that for you. Shouldn't take more than a week or two to develop.

Comment: Option 4 will be the route we most likely go. Thanks for your validation, and maybe mostly the fact that you don't know of any other solutions either. Other than 5, but that's what we're moving away from :)

Comment: @butallmj Two comments - 1) If you want to have that `deployment.xml` file easily - install your application, change the setting via console, save and then export. In the exported ear you will have that file already created so you can put it in your project in Eclipse.  2) You could upgrade your WebSphere license to [Tools editon](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/tools/) to get - an unlimited number of licenses of Rational Application Developer for that runtime.

Answer (score 1):

um nether answer is useful.

Go into WAS console and pick your application; example:

Enterprise Applications > my_application_ear > Class loader AND change the "class loader order and WAR class loader policy"

Comment: The question was - how to set it **in Eclipse**, not via admin console, so your answer is not relevant. And it was already discussed as Option 1) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Open the admin console within eclipse click server >> your server >> scroll down and under server infrastructure >> java process management  select class loader >> select new you can change it here